# Error when adding column with numeric name

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I currently have a MariaDB database with columns named after dates : `20200105`, `20200914` etc.
If I try to add a column using `ALTER TABLE dates ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS (test VARCHAR(255));`, it works and the `test` column is created.

If I type `ALTER TABLE dates ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS (20201205 VARCHAR(255));`, though (so, with a number replacing "test"), the creation does not work anymore and MariaDB tells me that there is an error with my SQL syntax.
I have tried to put quotes around the column name, but that does not work (not even with "test").

Is there something obvious I am missing ?

Comment: Did you try using ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks to escape the column name:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dates ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS (`20201205` VARCHAR(255));
```

But really best practice frowns upon the use of naming your database objects with mandatory backticks.  The reason for using a name like `20201205` as a column name is that you will forever be needing to escape it using backticks.  Also, from a data design point of view, your data should grow with new dates in terms of increasing the number of *records*, not columns.

Comment: Totally working, thanks ! That's right, but these dates actually correspond to versions (versions named after the date they are released), and my records are the number of devices in each version :) I'll wait for the mandatory 15 minutes then mark the answer as solving

Comment: @TheCodingPenguin Then in that case disregard my rant about date column names and good design -- it sounds as though you've vetted well your table design already.